# Failed to generate preview for user when sharing open graph story in ShareDialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I implemented the new Facebook SDK into my app with open graph stories. Process:

1. A dialog comes up with the Share on Facebook button
2. User clicks on Share on Facebook button that opens the Share Dialog
3. Open graph story appears in the dialog, user clicks the Post button in the top-right corner

**Error:** **Sometimes** (about 1 in 6) after step 2 when the Share Dialog comes up, it disappears with the error

```
Error Failed to generate preview for user.
```

**Open graph:**

```
final String fbNamespace = "myns";

        // Create an object
        ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                .putString("og:type", fbNamespace + ":badge")
                .putString("og:description", "Some description")
                .putString("og:title", "I've just unlocked a new badge!")
                .putString("og:url", "http://website.net")
                .putString("og:image", url)
                .build();

        // Create an action
        ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                .setActionType(fbNamespace + ":unlock")
                .putObject("badge", object)
                .build();

        // Create the content
        ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                .setPreviewPropertyName("badge")
                .setAction(action)
                .build();

        ShareDialog.show(MainActivity.this, content);
```

**Callback:**

```
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        shareDialog.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                Log.i("Share", "Success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.i("Share", "Cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.i("Share", "Error" + error.toString()); //Failed to generate preview for user
            }
        });
```

It's also strange that when the `ShareDialog` is displayed with the preset image, title and description, it takes about 3 seconds till the story appears. (this occurs every time)

**Note:** There are other questions looking for solution for the same error message but in those cases the dialog always disappears after showing up.

Comment: When the occasional error occurs are you passing the exact same parameters as when it works? If so I would suggest filing a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I am not sure if they can recreate the issue even if I pass the exact same parameters.

Comment: remove namespace from setActionType(...)

Answer (score 0):

Add your namespace in code:

```
// Create an action
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
    .setActionType(fbNamespace + ":unlock")
    .putObject(fbNamespace + ":badge", object) //add your namespace
    .build();

// Create the content
ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
    .setPreviewPropertyName(fbNamespace + ":badge") //add your namespace
    .setAction(action)
    .build();
```